# Javascript: vars and window.location

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm pretty new to Javascript. I'm working on a project and I need your help.

```
        function Function(var i)
    {
        var loca ="uploader.php?last=" +i;
        window.location =loca;
    }
```

This code is called using onclick that I set in a html form..
I don't know why, but when I try to run the code it doesn't do anything.
Im pretty sure the "+i" is the problem, Im not exactly sure how to add the i.
without the "i" the code runs well.

Comment: What are you passing as `i`?

Comment: Please don't name your function `Function()`, that already exists

Comment: `Function` is not a good name for a function for two reasons. Most importantly, it does not describe what it does. Secondly, `Function` in JavaScript refers to the `Function` object and by creating a function called `Function` you are shadowing it.

Comment: Also javascript does not require you type the arguments, so it should be (i) not (var i) ~ at least in my browser it complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `var` in a function parameter list. Try this:

```
 function Function(i)//replaced var
    {
        var loca ="uploader.php?last=" +i;
        window.location =loca;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify it as

```
function Function(i)
{
    var loca ="uploader.php?last="+i;
    window.location =loca;
}
```